# How to run a thread from a page in mainwindow ? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a page and added a button to this page.

And I put this page in a frame in the main window.

`MainUi.Content = new Page1();`

I want to start a thread in mainwindow when I click the button.

**In MainWindow**

```
namespace WpfApp3
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SendMessage()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is a test massage.");
        //And more
    }
}
```

**In Page**

```
namespace WpfApp3.Pages
{

    public partial class Page1: Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SendMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             SendMessage(); 
             //I want run this thread from here
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inject the `Page` with a reference to the window as suggested by @Nawed Nabi Zada, or you could get a reference to the parent window of the page using the static `Window.GetWindow` method:

```
private void SendMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow win = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
    win.SendMessage();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks worked! The window definition was not the only one I had to change to MainWindow.

MainWindow win = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

Comment: @SeyfullahNazikkol: `win` should be of type `MainWindow`. Please see my edit.